# PHP - Exporting CSV Files

Tags: php

I have written a script, which exports a CSV file with informations from Mysql databse. This script is working without problem under Linux Server(Apache) but it dosen't work under Windows Server(Apache).

I think the Problem is here with this headers!!!

```php
header('Content-Type: text/x-csv');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=iBlock_download.csv');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Can anyone here help?

Thanks

The Script is here:

```
header('Content-Type: text/x-csv');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=iBlock_download.csv');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");


    include('./lib/sqlString.php');
    $_id=$_GET['_id'];



$ResultPointer = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM projekte where pro_id='$_id'");
for($i = 0, $Export = ""; $i < mysql_num_rows($ResultPointer); $i++)
{

$Daten = mysql_fetch_object($ResultPointer);

$Spalte[] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $Daten->pro_id);
$Spalte[] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $Daten->pro_desc);
$Spalte[] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $Daten->pro_exp);
$Spalte[] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $Daten->pro_animal_nr);
$Spalte[] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $Daten->pro_organ);
$Spalte[] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $Daten->pro_treatment);
$Spalte[] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $Daten->pro_comment);
$Spalte[] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $Daten->pro_genotype);
$Spalte[] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $Daten->pro_start_date);
$Spalte[] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $Daten->pro_aktion);
$Spalte[] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $Daten->pro_txt1);
$Spalte[] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $Daten->pro_aktion);
$Spalte[] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $Daten->pro_user_name);

$ResultPointer2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pro where fn_pro_id ='$Daten->pro_id'");
$sume=mysql_num_rows($ResultPointer2);

for($i = 0, $Export = ""; $i < mysql_num_rows($ResultPointer2); $i++)
{
$sume=mysql_num_rows($ResultPointer2);

$Daten2 = mysql_fetch_object($ResultPointer2);
$Spalte[] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $Daten2->fn_desc);
$Spalte[] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $Daten2->fn_order_date);

    }

for($j = 0; $j < count($Spalte); $j++)
{
$Export .= "\"" . $Spalte[$j] . "\"";
if($j != count($Spalte)-1)
{
$Export .= ";";
}
}
$Export .= "\r\n";
$Spalte = "";
}
echo $Export;
```

Comment: FIrst of all, you have two `content-type` headers in there. I'd get rid of the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First... don't know how your script does it but this is a very useful function when working with csv. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

However... Why do you have 2 header functions that defined content-type? text/html is not needed and I would just stick to

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
```

or

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

Comment: Thnaks for your Answer. the Problem ist solved. The Problem was on the first of the Script. I have "<?" and i think that couldn't understand apache under Windows. Just I edit it to <?PHP and then works again!! I'm stupid :).... Many Thnaks for you again